# Azure diagnostics with WCF hosted in azure

Tags: wcf, azure

Could someone please confirm whether azure diagnostics is possible for WCF hosted in azure?

I followed this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajid/archive/2010/04/30/basic-azure-diagnostics.aspx

After doing Trace.WriteLine("Information","testing").

I was expecting a WADTable on azure storage, but not appearing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What was your transfer period, filter level, and how long did you wait to see it appear?  Do you have the AzureDiagnostics trace listener in your config file (or added programmatically).  Nothing willl appear if you are not using the listener.

Diagnostics by default are aggregated locally and will never appear in your storage account unless you actually initiate a transfer with the correct filter level (Undefined will do it all).  There are billing reasons why that is the case, btw (it costs you money in Tx and storage).

Comment: Hi @dunnry, checked the transfer period and azure diagnostics lister. But still not creating wadlogstable table

Answer (score 0):

This blog post is about 18 months old and there have been some breaking changes for Windows Azure Diagnostics since then from SDK perspective. Please refer to the latest SDK documentation or these blog posts:

http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/configuration-changes-to-windows-azure-diagnostics-in-azure-sdk-v1-3/

http://blog.bareweb.eu/2011/03/implementing-azure-diagnostics-with-sdk-v1-4/